# newman the cli companion for postman not work with URL in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, newman, postman-newman

Configuration :

```
- task: NewmanPostman@4
        inputs:
          collectionSourceType: 'url'
          collectionURL: 'https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{collectionId}?apikey={apiKey}'
          environmentSourceType: 'url'
          environmentUrl: 'https://api.postman.com/environments/{enviormentId}?apikey={apiKey}'
          reporters: 'htmlextra'
          pathToNewman: '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman'
          htmlExtraDarkTheme: true
          htmlExtraReportTitle: 'ExploreFunctionalTestSummary'
          reporterHtmlExport: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
          verbose: true
          logLevel: detailed
          sslInsecure: false
```

Error : throwing issue ##[error]The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman' failed with exit code 1

Debug same scenario on local system after newman install, but got collection not loading ,

[Approch-1 to debug on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIHMG.png)

error: collection could not be loaded
unable to fetch data from url "*[https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{collectionId}?apikey={apiKey}*"](https://api.getpostman.com/collections/%7BcollectionId%7D?apikey=%7BapiKey%7D*%22)

Provide the correct approch to implement it without ollectionfile/enviormentfile

Comment: It appears the pipeline agent is different with your local system. May i know what agent(self-hosted? linux os version?) did you use? In addition, please share the pipeline error details of the task. Is the path `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman` correct? Looks like you should add `/s` :  `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/drop/Postman" which points to the working directory.

Comment: If it's self-hosted agent, please go to the machine, confirm the newman is in the path `/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman`, if it doesn't exist, you can install it following [guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman) with npm task.

Comment: agent : ubuntu-latest, tried using adding "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/drop/Postman" , still not working

Comment: NewMan is `preinstalled` on `Ubuntu-latest` agent. Check with script `newman --version`, the version is 6.1.1.  Please remove `pathToNewman` parameter for the task.  Please show the error details in the statement if it's failed.

Comment: if I am removing pathToNewman, i get  errors as
No specific path to newman, using default of 'newman'
No custom report configured
Reporter list is : htmlextra
URL used for environment
##[error]The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman' failed with exit code 1

Comment: The task is successful on my side, as per the error `/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman`, it appears you don't comment the parameter correctly on the task, I will share the detail in the reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NewMan is preinstalled on `Ubuntu-latest` agent, the version is `6.1.1`.

As per the [guide](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman):

1. If you would like to use a `different` version of newman, you can install with  npm task as below:

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: NewMan install
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'install newman@4.6.1 -g'
```

For the `pathToNewman` parameter, it points to the newman path if you don't want to use the default version.

[image]

**Unless** you have newman installed on the path `/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman`, please **remove** the parameter in the task `NewmanPostman@4`.

2. For the `htmlextra` reporter type, you need to install `newman-reporter-htmlextra` **ahead** via npm task:

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: NewMan reporter htmlextra install
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra'
```

My complete yaml below, i added the comment on the tasks.

```
pool: 
  VMImage: Ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: newman --version
    
  # - task: Npm@1                             # commented as i used default Newman
  #   displayName: NewMan install
  #   inputs:
  #     command: 'custom'
  #     customCommand: 'install newman@4.6.1 -g'

  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: NewMan reporter htmlextra install
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra'
  

  - task: NewmanPostman@4
    inputs:
      collectionSourceType: 'url'
      collectionURL: 'https://api.getpostman.com/collections/$(collectionid)?apikey=$(apiKey)'
      environmentSourceType: 'url'
      environmentUrl: 'https://api.postman.com/environments/$(environmentid)?apikey=$(apiKey)'
      reporters: 'htmlextra'
      #pathToNewman: '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.15.0/x64/bin/newman'    # comment it as i use default newman
      htmlExtraDarkTheme: true
      htmlExtraReportTitle: 'ExploreFunctionalTestSummary'
      # reporterHtmlExport: 'drop/Postman'             # i used default newman path for the output path
      verbose: true
      logLevel: detailed
      sslInsecure: false
  

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

[image]

Check the report in artifact:
[image]

Edit: Add the variable list:

[image]

Comment: /usr/local/bin/newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/{collectionId}?apikey={apiKey} --reporter-htmlextra-darkTheme --reporter-htmlextra-title ExploreFunctionalTestSummary -r htmlextra -n 1 -e https://api.postman.com/environments/***?apikey={apiKey}





##[error]The process '/usr/local/bin/newman' failed with exit code 1

Note :  *** is show at enviormentId

Comment: `*** is show at enviormentId` could happen when the value is defined as secret variable, please note it could be any variables in your current pipeline. DevOps will automatically output the value as `*` in the log in this case. In addition, please fix both url parameters, add `/` after `collections` and `environments`. Define two Ids, apikey in variables. Use correct expression as `$(var)`. Please refer to my yaml sample, thanks.

Comment: You can ignore the `*` as it's only UI display in the log. But focus on the two whole url values, like `/` , variable syntax `$(var)` , and if the values of two ids, aplikey have `correct` values. You can double confirm the value in postman.